# NgBoostrap Datepicker change tooltips on month and year select

Tags: select, datepicker, tooltip, title, ng-bootstrap

How do I change the tooltips on the selection of the month and year?
I have successfully set the locale, my day and month descriptions are in the correct language (NL), but I still get the tooltips "select month" and "select year".

I tried the Injectable for the NgbDatepickerI18n, but this doesn't contain methods for the tooltips.

I am also not a fan of jQuery, so I want to stay away from that solution.